# Java Throws exception errors when fields are empty

Tags: java, database

I'm having this Exception when the textfield is empty it throws me an Exception error even though I am checking wheter its empty or not. Can you please look at the method and notify me what is wrong?

```
private void addStaff()
{
    ControlPanelCtr logCtr = new ControlPanelCtr();
    String username = userField.getText();
    String password = passField.getText();
    int secLevel = Integer.parseInt(secLvField.getText());
    if(userField.getText().equals("") || passField.getText().equals("") || secLvField.getText().equals(""))
    {
        notificationField.setText("All fields must be fullfiled.");
    }
    else
    {
        try{
            Login usrObj = new Login();
            if(usrObj.getUsername().equals(username))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Login logObj = new Login();
                admLogIdField.setText(String.valueOf(logObj.getId()));
                logCtr.addPeople(username, password, secLevel);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            notificationField.setText("Username already exists in the database.");
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The stacktrace tells you where the error is. Read the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have a check for `secLvField` to be non-empty, but it is done too late: you check the field after trying to parse it for an integer, which, of course, throws an error, so the check never arrives.

This line

```
int secLevel = Integer.parseInt(secLvField.getText());
```

will throw an exception when `secLevel` is empty, or when it does not represent a valid integer. You can wrap the parsing in a try/catch block to see if it is successful:

```
int secLevel;
try {
    secLevel = Integer.parseInt(secLvField.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    secLevel = -1; // If -1 is valid, pick some invalid value
}
if (secLevel == -1 || userField.getText().equals("") || passField.getText().equals("")) {
    notificationField.setText("All fields must be fullfiled.");
}
...
```